# How do I Copy a directory and contents to the same location with a new name

Tags: windows, command-line

I am going to answer this question myself to get the information out there because I was unable to find the answer on google. I need to run a command that will copy folder foo to the same location as foo and have it be named bar. (see images below)
[image: current state]
[image: desired state]

I tried several variations of the copy command and copy to another location rename then move back, but this was too complex for my taste. Please feel free to expand on my answer if I am missing something. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not saying this is perfect, but this is what worked for me

```
#first move to the desired working directory
cd C:\temp
#then run the following command using exactly the syntax below
xcopy .\foo .\bar\
```

This is what worked for me.